# Do Firefox 37 and IE9 support any kind of word break style?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

Do Firefox 37 and IE9 support any kind of word break style? I tried many of them, and none are working, they work only in Chrome. I'm trying to make this word break to work inside select, on options. Also, `show()` and `hide()` do not work on IE9, maybe someone knows why? Here is my current project:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <!-- none of these styles work on ff or ie9... -->
    <style>
        select {
            word-break: break-word;
            -ms-word-break: break-word;
            word-break: break-word;
            word-wrap: break-word;
            -webkit-hyphens: auto;
            -moz-hyphens: auto;
            display: inline-block;
            white-space: pre-wrap;
            white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
            white-space: -pre-wrap;
            white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
            word-wrap: break-word;
            -ms-word-break: break-all;
        }
    </style>
    <head>
        <title>Site Title</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1 style="margin-left:100px;">My List Box Source Example</h1>
        <!-- In style, "word-wrap:break-word" makes items appear over multiple lines if needed, works only on chrome, ff and ie9 broken -->
        <select name="sometext" multiple="multiple" style="width:200px; height:250px; resize:none; margin-left:100px; word-break: break-word;" id="mylist">
            <option value="1">VeryLongText123456VeryLongText123456VeryLongText123456VeryLongText123456VeryLongText123456VeryLongText123456END</option>
            <option value="3">Text1</option>
            <option value="5">Text2</option>
            <option value="6">Text3</option>
            <option value="7">Text4</option>
            <option value="9">Text5</option>
            <option value="12">abc6</option>
            <option value="14">SomeRandomText</option>
            <option value="45">ghi8</option>
            <option value="16">jkl9</option>
            <option value="11">zzz</option>
            <option value="32">xxx</option>
            <option value="73">LastItemHere</option>
        </select>
        
        <h2 style="margin-left:100px;">Search field</h2>
        <textarea rows="2" cols="45" style="margin-left:100px; resize:none; overflow-y:hidden;" id="searchfield"></textarea><br /><br />
        <input id="FilterButton" type="submit" style="margin-left:200px; width: 125px" value="Filter List" class="radius button"/><br /><br />
 
        <script src="jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // Titles - when mouse over entry
            options = document.getElementById("mylist").getElementsByTagName("option");

            for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                options[i].title = options[i].text;
            }
            
            $("#FilterButton").click(function () {
                //Show and hide works on chrome and ff, ie9 broken
                var searchText = $("#searchfield").val();
                var list = document.getElementById("mylist");
                for (var c = 0; c < list.length; c++) {
                    if(searchText != null && searchText != '') {
                        var index = list[c].text.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase());
                        if(index >= 0) {
                            $('#mylist option[value=' + list[c].value + ']').show();
                        }
                        else {
                            $('#mylist option[value=' + list[c].value + ']').hide();
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#mylist option[value=' + list[c].value + ']').show();
                    }
                }
            });
    </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to MDN, word-breaking is supported since FF 15 and IE 5.5

https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/CSS/word-break

You should specify the HTML lang attribute too, though (i.e. `<html lang="en">`). And AFAIK it works on a vocabular, so it's unlikely your example will ever work.

Comment: Well, it works on chrome, but ff and ie doesnt support word breaking in html select. As you can see in my example, first item(option) in select is very long, and chrome shows it over multiple lines correctly, but ff and ie9 doesnt support much features...